# Run a script on all recently modified files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, find, touch, stat

I would like to:

1. Find latest modified file in a folder
2. Change some files in the folder
3. Find all files modified after file of step 1
4. Run a script on these files from step 2

This this where I've end up:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(find /home -type f -exec stat \{} --printf="%y\n" \; |
     sort -n -r |
     head -n 1)
echo $var
sudo touch -d $var /home/foo
find /home/ -newer /home/foo
```

Can anybody help me in achieving these actions ?

Comment: You'll want to use `stat`: look at the `-c` options to print the file name and file mtime. You'll need to do that as step 1 and then in step 3.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus This is what I have been trying

var=$(find /home -type f -exec stat \{} --printf="%y\n" \; |
     sort -n -r |
     head -n 1)
sudo touch -d $var /home/foo
find /home -newer /home/foo)

Answer (score 1):

Use `inotifywait` instead to monitor files and check for changes

```
inotifywait -m -q -e modify --format "%f" {Path_To__Monitored_Directory}
```

Also, you can make it output to file, loop over it's contents and run your script on every entry.

```
 inotifywait -m -q -e modify --format "%f" -o {Output_File} {Path_To_Monitored_Directory}
```

sample output:

```
 file1
 file2
```

### Example

We are monitoring directory named `/tmp/dir` which contains `file1` and `file2`.
The following script which monitor the whole directory and echo the file name:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read ch
do
    echo "File modified= $ch"
done < <(inotifywait -m -q -e modify --format "%f" /tmp/dir)
```

Run this script and modify `file1` `echo "123" > /tmp/dir/file1`, the script will output the following:

```
File modified= file1
```

Also you can look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287230/bash-script-to-check-if-a-file-is-modified-or-not/287352)